# Mapnik not -85.0511º to 85.0511º shape issue

Tags: python, gis, shapefile, map-projections, mapnik

I have a shape that boundaries goes from -180º to 180º on longitude, but on latitude, It goes from -90º to 83.64513º. In a front-end application using `leaflet`, when It asks for `mapnik` server the image of the tiles, I convert tile positions to latitude/longitude. Longitude works, but latitude doesn't. I'm using this [formula](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Mathematics) to convert:

```
lat = arctan(sinh(pi*(1 - 2*y/2^zoom))) * 180/pi
```

The problem (*I don't really know if It's the problem...*) is that this formula admits that latitude goes from -85.0511º to 85.0511º, then I'm getting erros like this image:

[image]

What could I do to workaround this problem? Change the shape size (then how can I do it?), maybe there's a generic formula that I could pass any latitude or I'm missing some step.

Instead of using the formula above, I also tried using this [code](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/globalmaptiles.py) with the `GoogleTile` method. Got the same results...

Here is the code I'm using:

```
@app.route('/tiles/<z>/<x>/<y>', methods=['GET'])
def tiles(z, x, y):
    filename = tiles_path + r"tile_%s_%s_%s.png" % (z, x, y,)
    filename = filename.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    z = float(z); x = int(x); y = int(y)
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        x_1, y_1 = num2deg(x, y, z)
        x_2, y_2 = num2deg(x + 1, y + 1, z)
        envelope = mapnik.Envelope(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)
        mapnik_map.zoom_to_box(envelope)
        mapnik.render_to_file(mapnik_map, filename, "png")
    return send_file(filename)

def num2deg(xtile, ytile, zoom):
    n = 2.0 ** zoom
    lon_deg = xtile / n * 360.0 - 180.0
    lat_rad = atan(sinh(pi * (1 - 2 * ytile / n)))
    lat_deg = degrees(lat_rad)
    return lon_deg, lat_deg
```

If I change the `aspect_fix_mode` to `ADJUST_CANVAS_HEIGHT`:

```
mapnik_map.aspect_fix_mode = mapnik.aspect_fix_mode.ADJUST_CANVAS_HEIGHT
```

I don't have the problem above, but setting this, I get the map stretched out
and distorted.

Here is the [shapefile](https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/blob/master/110m_cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp) I'm using.

---

**EDIT:**

Mapnik default projection:

```
map_obj.srs
>>> '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'
map_obj.layers[0].srs
>>> '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

Tried to modify the map and layer `srs` like this:

```
mapnik_map = mapnik.Map(256, 256, "+init=epsg:3857")
...
layer = mapnik.Layer("layer_name", "+init=epsg:4326")
```

But nothing is rendered specially when the map `srs` is set.

Comment: No idea about Mapnik, does it mandate tiles in [Pseudo-Mercator](http://epsg.io/3857)? The data appears to be in [EPSG:4326](http://epsg.io/4326), which is one of the supported Tile formats in the code you reference `TMS Global Geodetic Profile`

Comment: Please, see edit. [Here](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/GettingStartedInPython), this is said: _the 'map.srs' is the target projection of the map and can be whatever you wish_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I was making a huge mistake about which projection standard to use. As my data is in `epsg:4326`, I decided to change everything to suit this standard. Here is what I did to make things work:

```
# creating the map
map = mapnik.Map(map_size, map_size, '+init=epsg:4326')

# creating a layer
layer = mapnik.Layer('layer', "+init=epsg:4326")

# tile to degree conversion (globalmaptiles.py adaptation)
# GlobalGeodetic.TileBounds
def tile2deg(tx, ty, zoom):
    res = 180 / 256.0 / 2**zoom
    return (
        tx*256*res - 180,
        ty*256*(-res) + 90,
        (tx+1)*256*res - 180,
        (ty+1)*256*(-res) + 90
    )

# tile2deg usage
map_bounds = tile2deg(x, y, z)
envelope = mapnik.Envelope(*map_bounds)
map.zoom_to_box(envelope)
```

Front-end:

```
// leaflet map configuration
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1,
    subdomains: [],
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
    tms: false,
});
```

Hope to help someone newbie like me in the future :)